# How to stop content from scrolling under fixed header to cover the background margin

Tags: html, css

Simple concept, hard to explain. Please see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tkyoung75/TZWEY/
The problem that I am having is that I want a border image around the page, like a desktop, and then a fixed header always at the top (likewise for footer) and then the content to scroll inside of that. Only problem is that when I scroll down, the content scrolls under the header and then reappears above it. Is there any way to stop it from reappearing? I am considering fixed size content window size with overflow-y: scroll but dont want extra scroll bars. Any suggestions / solutions?

html:

```
<body>
    <header>HEADER</header>
    <div id="content">
        blah<br>blah<br>times 40 or so to get a scroll effect.
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 17px;
    background-color: green;
    }
header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%
    }
#content {
    background-color: white;
    }
```

Comment: in `header` add `top:0;border-top:17px solid green;`

Comment: Ok, thank you, so I include that part of the background image into the header, which is a solution. are there any other alternatives that will not require image manipulation?

Comment: I copied text as suggested and it didn't work. It took away the full width of the div, and it didnt stop scrolling into the margin. I presume that the intended effect was to include the top section of the page margin in the header, however it is an image in the margin, not just green. Therefore to apply this as a solution I would have to crop out the top portion of the background image, add it to the header, and match it to the rest of the background image. It is a possible solution, but I am hoping there is a better one.